# Binary output to file in random positions in C++

Tags: c++, binary, append, ofstream

I'm beginning to feel awkwardly stupid, but I have a problem with outputting binary data to a file.
I have a file, let's say, 1000 bytes long. What I would like to do, in C++, is simply opening the file, replace ONE byte in a given position (let's say, the i-th byte), and close it.

File before operation:
    AAAAAA
File after operation:
    AAABAA

What is the easiest way to do so? I tried to open it with a ofstream.open, with the following modes:

```
ios::binary|ios::out
ios::binary|ios::app
ios::binary|ios::ate
```

All of these affected the actual size of the file after the operation. What should I do? I'm beginning to feel desperate.

Thank you very much and merry christmas to everybody!

Matteo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides binary mode, you need to open it in `out` *and* `in` modes. This corresponds to the `fopen` mode `"r+b"` which opens a file for reading and writing, and doesn't truncate the file if it exist (in fact, it *must* exist or you will fail to open the file).

References:

- [`std::basic_filebuf::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)
- [`std::fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen)